# a-law/raw audio data

Tags: audio, hex, alsa

I have spent the evening messing around with raw A-law audio input/output from the built in ALSA tools aplay and arecord, and passing them through an offline moving average filter I have written.

My question is: the audio seems to be encoded using values between 0x2A and 0xAA - a range of 128. I have been reading through [this](http://www.eetasia.com/ARTICLES/2001MAY/2001MAY21_NTEK_DSP_AN.PDF) guide which is informative but doesn't really explain why and offset of 42 (0x2A) has been chosen. The file I used to examine this was a square wave exported from audacity as unsigned 8-bit 8kHz audio and examined in a hex editor.

Can anyone shed some light on how A-law is encoded in a file?

Comment: A-law is just a straightforward mapping on the original waveform sample values; see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-law.

Comment: No, it is actually a companded 8-bit representation of a 12 bit signal, not a linear mapping. I have of course already read the wikipedia article, I was hoping for something a little more in-depth... For example why all the data is in the range 2A to AA?

Comment: I never said it was a linear mapping.  I can't think of any reason why you're only getting particular values.

Comment: Oh hang on.  You said your input waveform was a square wave; that only has two values...

Answer (score 0):

This may help;

**/dev/dsp**

*8000 frames per second, 8 bits per frame (1 byte);*

```
# Max volume = \xff (or \x00).
# No volume = \x80 (the middle).
```